# Why aren't my anacron jobs running?

Tags: 16.04, cron, anacron

`cron` is running, but no `anacron` jobs run. It's not a localized thing: *none* of them have been running for quite some time. (Clearly, I wasn't paying attention.)

I've checked all the usual `cron`-like things, but this message is found in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Jan  9 12:22:41 skmaiwlm anacron[31411]: Can't chdir to /var/spool/anacron: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3):

The `syslog` message turned out to be the answer to my question. All I had to do was create `/var/spool/anacron` and I tested everything using a solution I found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761658/manually-run-an-anacron-job)

```
sudo mkdir /var/spool/anacron
sudo anacron -f -n
```

I then was able to watch things progress normally in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
sudo less +F /var/log/syslog
```

```
Jan  9 12:23:18 skmaiwlm anacron[31500]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2018-01-09
Jan  9 12:23:18 skmaiwlm anacron[31500]: Will run job `cron.daily'
Jan  9 12:23:18 skmaiwlm anacron[31500]: Will run job `cron.weekly'
Jan  9 12:23:18 skmaiwlm anacron[31500]: Will run job `cron.monthly'
Jan  9 12:23:18 skmaiwlm anacron[31500]: Jobs will be executed sequentially
Jan  9 12:23:18 skmaiwlm anacron[31500]: Job `cron.daily' started
```

System happiness restored.